# How to call CURL in magento 2 for curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)

Tags: magento2, curl

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
```

How to call in magento 2.  I tried

```
    $this->_curl->setOption(CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use curl in magento 2

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
 */
protected $_curl;

/**
 * @param Context                             $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
) {
    $this->_curl = $curl;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    //if the method is get
    $this->_curl->get($url);
    //if the method is post
    $this->_curl->post($url, $params);
    //response will contain the output in form of JSON string
    $response = $this->_curl->getBody();
}
```

- $url => contain the endpoint url.
- $params => it’s an array, if you want to attach extra parameters in
  url.
- $response => it will contain the output in json form.

**I hope this will help**

Comment: yes, you are right but i want to call $headersize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE); in magento 2

Comment: Please check the `_invokeApi` function in `CurlClient` Class https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/dev/tests/api-functional/framework/Magento/TestFramework/TestCase/Webapi/Adapter/Rest/CurlClient.php. You can get the header size in response header index. I hope this will help

Comment: hmm, I am trying